# How to Require a Field Based on Specific Values from a Dropdown Field in React Json Schema

Tags: jsonschema, react-jsonschema-forms

How to conditionally require or de-require a field based on the selected value from another field?

Goal:

- Require "Input Code" field if country selected is Portugal o Vietnam
- Otherwise, do not require "Input Code" field

This is a nested schema form:

```
const schema = {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "myGroup": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "My Group",
      "properties": {
        "country": {
          "type": "string",
          "title": "Country",
          "enum": ["", "RO", "PT", "JP", "VN"],
          "enumName": ["", "Romania", "Portugal", "Japan", "Vietnam"]
        },
        "code": {
          "type": "string",
          "title": "Input Code"
        }
      },
      "required": ["country"],
      "dependencies": {
        "country": {
          "oneOf": [
            {
              "not": {
                "properties": {
                  "country": { "enum": ["PT", "VN"] }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "properties": {
                "country": { "enum": ["PT", "VN"] }
              },
              "required": ["code"]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
     }
   },
 };
```

Here's a working code, but I'm getting 2 extra validation errors
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-json-schema-require-field-based-on-another-field-selection-bbgrh?file=/src/index.js

- .myGroup should NOT be valid
- .myGroup should match exactly one schema in oneOf

[image]

Comment: Is there an option to upgrade the version of react-jsonschema-form?

Comment: @ŹmicierJaraševič Unfortunately, no. It's extensively used and upgrading will break the app. I actually ended up ditching the dependencies and went on to use combination of Form's onChange, validate, custom fields to ui:fields that will allow me to capture field on change events, then pass the data between them :( It was so tedious. But figuring above is way more tedious and stressful.

By the way, is this already beyond Json Schema Form's capability and purpose? Am I pushing it too far?

Comment: @ŹmicierJaraševič I tried 1.8.1 out of curiosity, but it's the same.

Comment: yeap, but they have v2 and v3 now, but ti's another name for the npm package